# Microsoft Graph APIにリクエストを投げてもエラーになる

Tags: node.js, azure, microsoft-graph

Microsoft公式のチュートリアルに沿ってアプリ作成し、サインインまではできアクセストークンの取得はできました。
しかし、途中のメールの取得や予定表の取得のリクエストを投げると、以下のエラーが発生してデータを取得することができません。

▼エラー

```
"FetchError: request to https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages?$top=10&$select=subject,from,receivedDateTime,isRead&$orderby=receivedDateTime DESC failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate"
```

Graphエクスプローラーで同じリクエストを投げてデータが取得できることは確認できているので、AzureADやアプリ側の設定だと思うのですが、原因が特定できません。
原因と解決方法をお分かりの方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

●参考：Outlook のメール、予定表、および連絡先を取得する Node.js アプリの記述
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/outlook/rest/node-tutorial

ソースはチュートリアルのままです。

```js
      // Initialize Graph client
      const client = graph.Client.init({
        authProvider: (done) => {
          done(null, accessToken);
        }
      });

      try {
        // Get the 10 newest messages from inbox
        const result = await client
        .api('/me/mailfolders/inbox/messages')
        .top(10)
        .select('subject,from,receivedDateTime,isRead')
        .orderby('receivedDateTime DESC')
        .get();

        parms.messages = result.value;
        res.render('mail', parms);
      } catch (err) {
        parms.message = 'Error retrieving messages';
        parms.error = { status: `${err.code}: ${err.message}` };
        parms.debug = JSON.stringify(err.body, null, 2);
        res.render('error', parms);
      }
```

よろしくお願いします。

追記
別のチュートリアルアプリでは同じリクエストでデータを取得することができます。  
ただ、何がどう違うのかがよくわかりません。また使いたいのは質問している方なので、解決したいです。

●参考：ユーザーをサインインして、JavaScript シングルページ アプリケーション (SPA) から Microsoft Graph API を呼び出す  
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa

Comment: "reason: unable to verify the first certificate"[直訳]理由：最初の証明書(certificate)が確認できません
というのがエラーメッセージの内容ですから、SSHの証明書などが期限切れになっていないかとか、最近設定を変更したことが原因じゃないかとか、あたりから調べてみてはどうでしょう。

Comment: AzureADのシークレット証明書になるのでしょうか。無期限に設定しています。  
また、質問欄に記載していませんでしたが、別のチュートリアルアプリでは同じリクエストでデータを取得することができます。  
ただ、何がどう違うのかがよくわかりません。また使いたいのは質問している方なので、解決したいです。  
  
●ユーザーをサインインして、JavaScript シングルページ アプリケーション (SPA) から Microsoft Graph API を呼び出す  
https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/azure/active-directory/develop/tutorial-v2-javascript-spa